# why is this Python code failing in the stomp library - missing message argument?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

The company I work for has a Python test script which posts a message to a AMQ (input) topic using Python 3.x. The test script is configured to consume resulting messages from an output topic.
I have written a Python script which receives the AMQ message on a topic, does it's processing and posts another message onto a different (output) topic.

My issue is this, when running the test script in Ubuntu v20 I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/robot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 348, in __receiver_loop
    self.process_frame(f, frame)
  File "/home/robot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 193, in process_frame
    self.notify(frame_type, f)
  File "/home/robot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 248, in notify
    notify_func(frame)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Here is the code which receives messages on the input topic, processes them and places messages on the output topic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import os
import threading
import logging
import signal
import stomp
import config_with_yaml as config
import sys
from src import factory

console = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('my-client')


class MyConfig:
    def __init__(self):

    # boiler plate config
 



config = MyConfig()


def connect_and_subscribe(conn):
    conn.connect(config.amq_username, config.amq_password, wait=True, headers={'client-id': config.client_id})
    conn.subscribe(destination=config.in_topic, id=config.subscription_id, ack='auto',
                   headers={'activemq.subscriptionName': config.subscription_name, 'activemq.prefetchSize': 1})


class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        logging.error('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        # MESSAGE PROCESSING START
        logging.debug('message recieved')
        logging.debug('headers: "%s"' % str(headers))
        logging.debug('message: "%s"' % message)
        logging.debug('processing "%s"  message' % config.name)

        df = factory.dataflow_factory(config.location, config.name.lower(), message)
        body = df.process()
        logging.debug('message processed: "%s"' % str(body))
        # # MESSAGE PROCESSING END

        # # Send response message
        self.conn.send(body=body, destination=config.out_topic)
        logging.debug('response sent')

    def on_disconnected(self):
        logging.debug('disconnected, reconnecting...')
        with self.conn.need_reconnect:
            self.conn.need_reconnect.notify()


class ConnectThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.conn = conn

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if not self.conn.is_connected():
                    logging.info("client ready to connect to AMQ")
                    connect_and_subscribe(self.conn)
                    with self.conn.need_reconnect:
                        self.conn.need_reconnect.wait()
            except Exception as ex:
                template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
                message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
                logging.warning(message)
                time.sleep(5)


class ActiveDaemon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.go_down)

        self.conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=config.hosts, keepalive=True, reconnect_attempts_max=1)
        self.conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=config.hosts, key_file=config.amq_key_file_location,
                          cert_file=config.amq_cert_file_location)
        self.conn.need_reconnect = threading.Condition()
        self.conn.set_listener('', MyListener(self.conn))

    def run(self):
        connection_thread = ConnectThread(self.conn)
        connection_thread.start()

        logging.info("client daemon running")

        while not self.stop:
            time.sleep(2)

        self.conn.disconnect()

    def go_down(self, signum, frame):
        logging.info("Exit command received")
        self.stop = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("client starting...")
    daemon = ActiveDaemon()
    logging.info("client daemon created")
    daemon.run()
```

Here is the consumer code from the script.

```
class Consumer(ActiveMQConnection):
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: str, cert_key_location: str, cert_file_location: str, username: str,
                 password: str, subscription_topic: str):
        self.conn = None
        self.subscription_topic = subscription_topic
        self.class_name = self.MessageListener
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        ActiveMQConnection.__init__(self, host=host, port=port, cert_key_location=cert_key_location,
                                    cert_file_location=cert_file_location, is_consumer=True)

    def connect_and_subscribe(self, expected_msg_count: int, time_limit_seconds: int) -> int:
        global EXPECTED_MSG_COUNT
        EXPECTED_MSG_COUNT = expected_msg_count
        while EXPECTED_MSG_COUNT != ACTUAL_MSG_COUNT:
            self.conn = self.get_connection()

        return ACTUAL_MSG_COUNT

    class MessageListener:
        def __init__(self, conn: object):
            self.conn = conn

        def on_error(self, headers, message):
            logging.error("Received an error with message: " + message)

        def on_message(self, headers, message):
            global ACTUAL_MSG_COUNT
            logging.debug("Message Received: " + message)
            ACTUAL_MSG_COUNT += 1
```

Now, here's the strange thing. A colleague can run this code without error in Ubuntu (not sure of the version), same Python version 3.6 (also occurs with 3.8) with the same AMQ instance (dockerised) and the same code to process the messages (also dockerised).

I've tried adding output to the stomp library, to no avail.

I did note though that I was observing two indentical log messages from within stomp's transport.py script in the listener's loop:

```
INFO:stomp.py:Received frame: 'CONNECTED', len(body)=0
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = connected
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = connected
INFO:stomp.py:Sending frame: 'SUBSCRIBE'
INFO:stomp.py:notify_func = <bound method HeartbeatListener.on_connected of <stomp.connect.StompConnection11 object at 0x7fb7033b2160>>
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = before_message
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = before_message
INFO:stomp.py:notify_func = <bound method ConnectionListener.on_before_message of <stomp.connect.StompConnection11 object at 0x7fb7033b2160>>
INFO:stomp.py:Received frame: 'MESSAGE', len(body)=21
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = message
INFO:stomp.py:notify_func = <bound method Consumer.MessageListener.on_message of <__main__.Consumer.MessageListener object at 0x7fb702c9bf60>>
INFO:stomp.py:Receiver loop ended
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = receiver_loop_completed
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = receiver_loop_completed
INFO:stomp.py:notify_func = <bound method ConnectionListener.on_receiver_loop_completed of <stomp.connect.StompConnection11 object at 0x7fb7033b2160>>
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = disconnected
INFO:stomp.py:frame type = disconnected
Exception in thread Thread-2:
```

Can't be sure if that should be happening or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your listener classes according to `stomp.py` version. Most probably different OSes comes with different stomp.py version, see `python -c "import stomp; print(stomp.__version__)"` . Check the version of stomp module and adapt your listener/consumer accordingly.

After major v6+, most of the listener class function parameters changed. For example

```
on_error(self, headers, message) # before 4.1.21
```

to

```
on_error(self, frame) # after 6.1.0
```

See all changes in the main documentation http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/stomp.html?highlight=listener#module-stomp.listener